# What does 'no_implementor' mean when running AjaxSpider in Python ZAP module?

Tags: python-3.x, zap

## 1.) Code used

if useAjaxSpider:

```
# Ajax Spider the target URL
pprint('Start Ajax Spider -> ' + ajax.scan(url=target, inscope=None))
# Give the Ajax spider a chance to start
time.sleep(10)
while (ajax.status != 'stopped'):
    print('Ajax Spider is ' + ajax.status)
    time.sleep(5)
for url in applicationURL:
    # Ajax Spider every url configured
    pprint('Ajax Spider the URL: ' + url + ' -> ' +
           ajax.scan(url=url, inscope=None))
    # Give the Ajax spider a chance to start
    time.sleep(10)
    while (ajax.status != 'stopped'):
        print('Ajax Spider is ' + ajax.status)
        time.sleep(5)
print('Ajax Spider scan completed')
```

## 2.) Going in Infinite Loop

'Ajay Spider is no_implementor'

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout ZAP's new API docs: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/#using-ajax-spider

"no_implementor" "No Implementor" likely means that you don't have the AjaxSpider addon installed. (It means, you don't have anything impelmenting the functionality you're trying to use.)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from zapv2 import ZAPv2

# The URL of the application to be tested
target = 'https://public-firing-range.appspot.com'
# Change to match the API key set in ZAP, or use None if the API key is disabled
apiKey = 'changeme'

# By default ZAP API client will connect to port 8080
zap = ZAPv2(apikey=apiKey)
# Use the line below if ZAP is not listening on port 8080, for example, if listening on port 8090
# zap = ZAPv2(apikey=apikey, proxies={'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8090', 'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:8090'})

print('Ajax Spider target {}'.format(target))
scanID = zap.ajaxSpider.scan(target)

timeout = time.time() + 60*2   # 2 minutes from now
# Loop until the ajax spider has finished or the timeout has exceeded
while zap.ajaxSpider.status == 'running':
    if time.time() > timeout:
        break
    print('Ajax Spider status' + zap.ajaxSpider.status)
    time.sleep(2)

print('Ajax Spider completed')
ajaxResults = zap.ajaxSpider.results(start=0, count=10)
# If required perform additional operations with the Ajax Spider results

# TODO: Start scanning the application to find vulnerabilities
```

Comment: It is not mentioned anywhere to specifically install the AjaxSpider module. It should come with ZAPv2 package itself is what they are implying.

Comment: I'm not talking about a python module. The ZAPv2 package contains the client API for the Ajax spider. However, if you're trying to drive ZAP via its API without the needed ZAP add-on installed then theres nothing for the client API to interact with.

Comment: I set 'useAjaxSpider = True' and am using the  ajaxSpider call in the function while trying to hit the target. Using the ZAP API specified in the ZAP Desktop version. What am I missing? New to this ZAP, sorry if it is a basic question